# Regex to remove commas in string if criteria are met in R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I would like to remove commas from a list of addresses if 1) the comma follows any number or 2) the comma follows a number with a single letter.

So if my input looked like this:

```
library("data.table")
Input <- data.table(Var = c("43, Badger Drive", "45A, Badger Drive",
                            "45BB, Badger Drive", "Zebra House, 200A Badger Drive", 
                            "F27, 20 Badger Drive", "78, Badger 24 Drive"))
```

My output would look like this:

```
Output <- data.table(Var = c("43 Badger Drive", "45A Badger Drive", 
                            "45BB, Badger Drive"," Zebra House, 200A Badger Drive", 
                            "F27, 20 Badger Drive", "78 Badger 24 Drive"))
```

This almost achieves my first criteria, but removes the comma on line 5 after F27, nor am I sure how it can be modified to achieve my second criteria:

```
Input[, New_Input := gsub("([[:digit:]]),", "\\1", Input$Var)]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
gsub("([[:digit:]][[:alpha:]]?),", "\\1", Input$Var)
```

Here,

- `([[:digit:]][[:alpha:]]?)` - Capturing group 1: a digit and an optional letter
- `,` - a comma

The match is only replaced with the Group 1 contents, so the comma is only removed when  it is immediately preceded with a digit or a digit+letter.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V7r7LQ/1).